# WiTap Example in iPhone

Tags: iphone

This is the following piece of code from WiTap,

```
- (void) send:(const uint8_t)message
{
if (_outStream && [_outStream hasSpaceAvailable])
        if([_outStream write:(const uint8_t *)&message maxLength:sizeof(const uint8_t)] == -1)
                [self _showAlert:@"Failed sending data to peer"];
 }

 - (void) activateView:(TapView*)view
{
    NSLog(@"ACTIVATE TAG: %d", [view tag]); 
    //[self send:[view tag] | 0x80];
    [self send:[view tag]];
 }

 - (void) deactivateView:(TapView*)view
 {
    NSLog(@"DEACTIVATE TAG: %d", [view tag]); 
    //[self send:[view tag] & 0x7f];
    [self send:[view tag]];

 }
```

Is it possible to send a file using WiTap ?
How to send NSData using the send method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it's the wrong way to do it.
For what you're trying to do I recommend to use SimpleNetworkStreams (that's the name of the sample).

If you need to use multiple connection here's what you need
http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/index.html